# Detecting encoding of sting and converting it

Tags: json, r, encoding

I have string:

```
string <- "{'text': u'Kandydaci PSL do Parlamentu Europejskiego  \\u2013 OKR\\u0118G nr 1: Obejmuje obszar wojew\\xf3dztwa pomorskiego z siedzib\\u0105 ok... http://t.co/aZbjK7ME1O', 'created_at': u'Mon May 19 11:30:07 +0000 2014'}"
```

As you can see I have some codes instead of letters. As far as I know there are UTH-8 codes for polish characters like ą, ć, ź, ó and so on. How can I convert this string to obtain the output

```
"{'text': u'Kandydaci PSL do Parlamentu Europejskiego  \\u2013 OKRĄG nr 1: Obejmuje obszar województwa pomorskiego z siedzibą ok... http://t.co/aZbjK7ME1O', 'created_at': u'Mon May 19 11:30:07 +0000 2014'}"
```

Comment: What does `Encoding(string)` return? Have you tried `Encoding(string)<-"UTF-8"`?

Comment: It doesn't change anything.

Comment: Ah, I see, the slashes are escaped. Is that supposed to be JSON? Because it's not valid JSON (http://jsonlint.com/). If you had valid JSON data and ran it thought a library to import JSON data, chances are the encoding will take care of itself. Right now you don't technically have any special (non-ascii) characters in your data.

Comment: But what if I want to treat it like 'normal' string and use regex to extract parts of it? Is it any way to replace codes with polish special characters?

Comment: If you want to use regular expressions, you're going to have to be much more specific about what you actually want to replace. You'll probably need to enumerate exactly what codes you want to replace since you only seem to want to replace a specific subset.

Comment: Ok, this code changes some signs and now it does have JSON format: `string <- stri_replace_all_fixed(string, c("'text': u'", "', 'created_at': u'", "'}"), 
                       c("\"text\": \"", "\", \"created_at\": \"", "\"}"), vectorize_all=FALSE)` but still teh output of fromJSON(string) is without polish characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a regular expression to find all escaped characters in the form `\udddd` and `\xdd`. We then take those values, and re-parse them to turn them into characters. Finally we replace the original matched values with the true characters

```
m <- gregexpr("\\\\u\\d{4}|\\\\x[0-9A_Fa-f]{2}", string)
a <- enc2utf8(sapply(parse(text=paste0('"', regmatches(string,m)[[1]], '"')), eval))
regmatches(string,m)[[1]] <- a
```

This will do them all. If you only want to do a subset, you could filter the vector of possible replacements.